# Graph Eccentrity Vector in x and y Component

Tags: orbital-elements

I have one year eccentricity value (the eccentricity magnitude only). I want to know the eccentricity vector in x and y component, so I use this below equation to get it (credit: Hengian Li):
[image]

After get the ex and ey components, I plot it. The graph is below

[image: My graph]

Actually, my goal is to get this graph (credit: Hengian Li):

[image: Reference graph]

My graph and the reference graph looks different. I don't know whats wrong with it. I hope anybody can help me to fix this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It might be hard to debug a plot, "what did I do wrong" questions are in general easier to answer when there's plenty of information about what was done and specifics on *how it was done*. If you have a computer program or script and it's not too long, it's fine to add it here. Indent by four spaces and it turns into a code block just like in Stack Overflow. It's not encouraged to ask a "debug my code" question here, but you can certainly add it to this question where you already show the equations you've used.

Comment: I noticed that the magnitude of your plot is much, much smaller than the plot in the goal graph. It's also not centered at the same point.  In fact, there is not much similarity at all.  I'd suspect it is your calculations that are at fault, not your plotting.  So some examples of your calculations (input values and results) would be good to add to your answer too.

Comment: @uhoh thank you for your response. Actually, there is no special code to plot it, I just using excel to make the plot

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you for your response. I think the calculation is not wrong, because I am using the equations in the book (figure 1 in this question). But, maybe 
there are steps I haven't done, but I don't know what is it